# Is it possible for Apache to send a 'pause' or 'wait' response to client while running a PHP/Perl script?

Tags: apache, http

When the Apache server receives a POST request, I want to immediately send back a response, stating that the client should wait and not send anything.

While at the same time client's request will be passed on to a script (either PHP or Perl). And then the script will send back a response to the client.

Is this possible? I know that it is possible for Apache to send a 4xx response header, so that the client would stop sending. But I want to run a script while the client has stopped sending and then have the client redirect to somewhere..

Answer (score 0):

There are a few HTTP status codes that may be of use IF you want to be fully REST-ful and use the HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc) and status codes

https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

In particular for what I am interpreting as your use case, status code `202 Accepted` may be correct for your use:

> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has
>   not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted
>   upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place.
>   There is no facility for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous
>   operation such as this.
>
> The 202 response is intentionally non-committal. Its purpose is to
>   allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a
>   batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without
>   requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist until
>   the process is completed. The entity returned with this response
>   SHOULD include an indication of the request's current status and
>   either a pointer to a status monitor or some estimate of when the user
>   can expect the request to be fulfilled.

Comment: 202 sounds promising. Is there a way I can send a 202 response from Apache to the client and then run a script in the mean time and have that script send a redirect to the client?

Comment: @John - you can use the 202 and a redirect together.  There is some buggy behavior described here - https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70273 but if you read the post made at `2015-08-17 16:35 UTC` by  `jeff at nd4c dot com` he demonstrates a way of doing it.  Of course, you haven't told us what language you are using on the back end, but I'm sure similar solutions are available for whatever tech stack you are using